# DRF return errors from model validation

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have models and serializers. Errors that are returned from the serializer are helpful because I can send them as a response to API and user can correct invalid data.

However, errors that are from models are useless for me. They return 500 error and they don't have a body that I can send back to the user.

Should I overide validate method even more to give me some usable errors or there is a method for that?

models

```
class School(models.Model):

    SUBJECT = (
       ('Math', 'Mathematic'),
       ('Eng', 'English'),
       ('Cesolved', 'Chemistry'),
   )

    name = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=50)
    subject = models.CharField(choices=SUBJECT, max_length=15, blank=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(f'{self.name} is {self.subject}')
```

serializers

```
class SchoolSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    subject = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=School.SUBJECT)

    def validate(self, data):
        name = data["name"]
        if (5 > len(name)):
            raise serializers.ValidationError({"IError": "Invalid name"})
 
        return data

    class Meta:
        model = School
        fields = "__all__"
```

views

```
class SchoolViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = School.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SchoolSerializer

    def create(self, request):
        serializer = SchoolSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

for example, if name is shorter than 5 i return a kinda helpful error but when name is to long and I let the django models return the error only thing that I get is 500 response and a print statement in terminal

```
django.db.utils.DataError: value too long for type character varying(50)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually DRf handles basics like required/non-required field checks, but if the error that model/database returns is not handled, I would advice to just add custom field level validation in serializer, like validate_name where you raise validation error if supplied argument violates expected behavior.

You can see detailed examples here https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#field-level-validation